# WPF find a control

Tags: wpf

I created a grid in procedural code on my WPF page.  Now I want to reference that grid.

```
Grid grid = (Grid)This.FindName("myGridName")
```

does not work.  Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an element in code, you need to also call the RegisterName method to allow FindName to work.

Comment: you are correct..That's exactly what I just found out too.  Thanks.